# Wordpress Admin Post Per Page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

This issue is related with wordpress 4.5.3, acf 3.8.8 , ajax and php.

I have a custom field which contains data retrieved from post type embedded with ajax response. Now, the problem is even if I add `posts_per_page => -1`, it returns post equal to default blog posts number. Can I exclude this and get all post?

I tried with query_posts and sending show posts parameter, but not excluding default blog post size. Can it be done like, as I just need this post per page to be change in admin, `if(is_admin())` and exclude default blog post number?

```
Return only 10

ajax request code :
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../wp-content/themes/megaintl/inc/admin.php?post_w=taxonomyTripEdit&tId=" + pId,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var results = JSON.parse(data);
                //var i = 1;
                $.each(results, function (key, data) {

                    var stringArray = data.split('-');
                    var selectedKey = stringArray.slice(1).join('-');
                    //alert(selectedKey);
                    if (selectedKey != '') {
                        var selectKey = selectedKey;
                        $('#acf-field_57b13a3e248ad').append($('<option ' + selectKey + '></option>').val(stringArray[0]).html(stringArray[0]));
                    } else {
                        $('#acf-field_57b13a3e248ad').append($('<option></option>').val(data).html(data));
                    }
                });

            }
        });


admin.php
 if(isset($_GET['tId'])) {
            $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'trip_category',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                //echo $term->term_id;
                if ($term->term_id == $_GET['tId']) {
                    $category = get_field('category_option_trips', 'trip_category_' . $_GET['tId']);

                }
            }
            $argsTrip = array(
                'post_type' => 'trip',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            );



            // query
            $tripSelect = array();
            $trip = new WP_Query($argsTrip);
            if ($trip) {
                while ($trip->have_posts()): $trip->the_post();
                    if (!empty($category)) {
```

match the array values with new trips

```
if (in_array(get_the_title(), $category)) {
                        $tripSelect[] = get_the_title() . '-selected';
                    } else {
                        $tripSelect[] = get_the_title();
                    }

                } else {
                    $tripSelect[] = get_the_title();
                }

            endwhile;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($query);
```

Comment: I don't get it, on which page are you ? post.php ? edit.php <- did you set screen options limit ?

Comment: I am on edit category page, and I have a multi-select custom field in which all post are embed with ajax $('#acf-field_57b13a3e248ad').append($('<option ' ...   with wp query , but posts_per_page => -1 is not working. I tried with some pre_get_posts on this, but its not working here.